# Cannot publish the google editor addon due to "Menu options not shown after App is installed..." error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, add-on, google-apps-marketplace

I am trying the publish my Google sheet addon to Google Workspace. After the review I got an email with following feedback:

**Menu - Menu options not shown after App is installed. Please ensure that the add-on correctly uses onInstall() and onOpen() to populate its menu. The menu items populate when the add-on is first installed and when a different file is opened. See Editor add-on authorization. , https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/concepts/editor-auth-lifecycle**

I added the the menu and it's working in test mode but I am stuck in this review process.

Here's some code of Code.gs file:

```
function onInstall(e) {
  onOpen(e);
}
var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();

function onOpen(e) {
// Adding menu to addons menu
if (e && e.authMode != ScriptApp.AuthMode.NONE)
{
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .createAddonMenu()
    .addItem('Enable/Disable', 'showSidebar')
    .addSeparator()
    .addItem('History ', 'openHistoryDialog')
    .addSeparator()
    .addItem('Buy credits', 'addCredits')
    .addSeparator()
    .addItem('Settings', 'settingsDialog')
    .addToUi();

    // Default value for enable or disable.
    userProperties.setProperty("enable_user", false);
  }
}
```

and here appscript.json

```
{
  "timeZone": "Asia/Karachi",
  "dependencies": {
  "enabledAdvancedServices": [
  {
    "userSymbol": "Sheets",
    "serviceId": "sheets",
    "version": "v4"
  }
]
},
   "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
   "oauthScopes": [
     "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
     "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
     "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
     "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request",
     "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui",
     "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.locale"
],
    "runtimeVersion": "V8"
}
```

thank you for help!

Answer (score 3):

The problem might be related with the way that the Add on is handling the menu, currently the menu in your code is displayed on a conditional statement assuming that the status of the event is different than `ScriptApp.AuthMode.NONE` however if for some reason this statement fails then the menu will fail to be displayed along with the menu items, they may be referring to that behavior when they mention:

> Menu options not shown after App is installed. Please ensure that the add-on correctly uses onInstall() and onOpen() to populate its menu. The menu items populate when the add-on is first installed and when a different file is opened.

You could check the example given in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/concepts/editor-auth-lifecycle#opening) as you are trying to detect the authorization mode:

```
function onOpen(e) {
  var menu = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createAddonMenu(); // Or DocumentApp.
  if (e && e.authMode == ScriptApp.AuthMode.NONE) {
    // Add a normal menu item (works in all authorization modes).
    menu.addItem('Start workflow', 'startWorkflow');
  } else {
    // Add a menu item based on properties (doesn't work in AuthMode.NONE).
    var properties = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
    var workflowStarted = properties.getProperty('workflowStarted');
    if (workflowStarted) {
      menu.addItem('Check workflow status', 'checkWorkflow');
    } else {
      menu.addItem('Start workflow', 'startWorkflow');
    }
  }
  menu.addToUi();
}
```

Notice that the menu is being created before the conditional statement that handles the current authorization mode is analyzed.

Comment: Thank you @Gabriel! Is there any issue declaring **var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();** globally in the script? I will edit this and re-submit for review.